# dyld: Library not loaded: libmysql.16.dylib (MAC)

Tags: mysql, c, macos, gcc, makefile

I started experimenting with the MySQL C API today, which I compiled today from source on my 10.6.8 macbook, and rolled out a quick makefile + app skeleton. I feel a bit rusty, though, because I can't seem to get it to link properly (fixed, now, it seems) or dynamically load the library (problem stated below).

The exact error I receive is below:

```
$ make clean && make
gcc -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -I/usr/local/mysql/include -lmysql -lpthread -ggdb -Wall -o adapter main.c adapter.c 

$ ./adapter
dyld: Library not loaded: libmysql.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /tmp/./adapter
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap
```

I looked around, and a lot of results regarding an `install_name_tool` came up. After reading through a few of those, though, I still don't completely understand what this actually does. There was a lot of talk about Frameworks, which didn't really fit into what I would expect to be involved in such a simple project..

Anyway, here is my code (including makefile).

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "adapter.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Version: %s\n", get_version());
    return 0;
}
```

**adapter.c**:

```
#include <mysql.h>

char *get_version () {
    return (char *)mysql_get_client_info();
}
```

**adapter.h**:

```
char *get_version ();
```

**Makefile**:

```
CC = gcc
MYSQL_FLAGS = -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -I/usr/local/mysql/include -lmysql -lpthread
CFLAGS = -ggdb -Wall
OBJS = 

adapter: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(MYSQL_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o adapter main.c adapter.c $(OBJS)

clean:
    @rm -f *~ *.o adapter
    @rm -rf *.dSYM
```

And, a side note, the files really do exist:

```
$ ls /usr/local/mysql/lib
libmysql.16.0.0.dylib   libmysql.dylib      libmysqlclient.dylib
libmysql.16.dylib       libmysqlclient.a    libmysqlclient_r.dylib

$ ls /usr/local/mysql/include
atomic          my_atomic.h     my_md5.h        myisampack.h        sslopt-case.h
base64.h        my_attribute.h  my_net.h        mysql.h             sslopt-longopts.h
config-win.h    my_base.h       my_no_pthread.h mysql_com.h         sslopt-vars.h
decimal.h       my_bit.h        my_nosys.h      mysql_time.h        t_ctype.h
errmsg.h        my_bitmap.h     my_pthread.h    mysql_version.h     thr_alarm.h
hash.h          my_charsets.h   my_stacktrace.h mysqld_error.h      thr_lock.h
keycache.h      my_config.h     my_sys.h        mysys               typelib.h
lf.h            my_dbug.h       my_time.h       mysys_err.h         violite.h
m_ctype.h       my_dir.h        my_tree.h       queues.h            waiting_threads.h
m_string.h      my_getopt.h     my_trie.h       service_versions.h  wqueue.h
my_aes.h        my_global.h     my_uctype.h     sha1.h
my_alarm.h      my_libwrap.h    my_vle.h        sha2.h
my_alloc.h      my_list.h       my_xml.h        sql_common.h
```

I have a gut feeling that something is wrong with my Makefile or it's an issue particular to Mac OS X, but in reality, I'm really not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [dynamic linker](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) error and has nothing to do with source code. There are a lot of ways to fix it. The simplest perhaps is to add `/usr/local/mysql/lib` to the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` before you run `adapter`. For example:

```
$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/lib"
$ ./adapter
```